# Is there a way to disable GestureArena in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to disable GestureArena which decides the preference of gestures,

is there any possible way to do this?

About [Gesture disambiguation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures#gesture-disambiguation)

Answer (score 1):

you can try an `IgnorePointer` widget or an `AbsorbPointer` widget.

`IgnorePointer` prevents its children from receiving pointer events but is itself invisible to hit testing.

`AbsorbPointer` prevents its subtree from receiving pointer events by terminating hit testing at itself.

Comment: Thanks @thomas, but it didn't help.